# Question count missing from network_user

Tags: bug, status-completed

Docs state that you get an int question_count from a network_user object but I'm not getting these fields back anymore - even when testing from
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-associated-users

The doc that states I should get it back is here:
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user

Is this a change to the API or have I got to change my call?

I'm currently using /me/associated to get the network users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an outage of the data backing that query, it was fixed a few hours ago.

`question_count` and `answer_count` should be being returned from `/associated` calls again.